# How many triangles with same color are there using $6$ and $n$ points?

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

How many triangles with same color are there using $6$ points?

How many triangles with same color are there using $n$ points?

It seems to be Ramsey numbers but in that we never prove there are two we prove there is minimum $1$ such triangle.For the second problem the book gave the answer

$$\binom{n}{3}-\frac{n*\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}}\rfloor*\lceil{\frac{n-1}{2}}\rceil}{2}$$

Which is colmpletly odd for me.Any hints?

**Edit**:We use two colors.None of three points are on one line and by same colore I mean both are blue or both are red.

Comment: Please, add details. How many colors do you use? How are these $n$ points arranged in order to form a triangle? How are different colored triangles considered to be the same?

Comment: @Crostul details added.